# How to optimize the size of image on website to very small as Apple?

Tags: image-optimization

How can Apple reduce image size so much and contain its quality?

For example:
http://images.apple.com/v/ipad/home/y/images/home/accessories_xlarge.jpg

This is a 2560x800px big image in just 218kb, and the image quality is good!

I've try some tools like https://tinypng.com/, it can do huge optimization, but it will reduce images quality.

So I still can't figure out what tool Apple uses, please help me out~~~

Thank you very much!
(And please forgive my poor english > <)

Comment: You can try out the `Save for Web & Devices` option in `Adobe Photoshop CSX` for that..I think that's the one which you are looking for..!

Comment: Also in comparing `PNG` with `JPEG` so `PNG` size stays quite very more  than the `JPEG` You can compress the image as to best as possible size with not loosing too much quality with the help of `Adobe Photoshop`.

Comment: Also I am confused that are you looking for some sort of API or a software to do this?

Comment: Yesterday I helped out a friend to compress a background `PNG` image of size 2.3+ MB with Resolution of 1917X799 to be compressed into as low as into `JPEG` file of size 611 KB with just loosing 20% quality and still the image looks great..!

Comment: For Reference Take a look at the site as : http://www.adscanyon.com

Comment: `PNG` Background Image Link : http://adscanyon.com/images/background-image.png

Comment: `JPEG` Background Image Link :http://adscanyon.com/images/background-image.jpg

Comment: Umair Shah Yousafzai, thank you very much! It's very helpful.
I use "Save for Web" as you mentioned, and compress very well!
A 1920x1080 image can be compressed into just 65kb, oh yeah~~~